# Data type mismatch C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi I'm having an issue when selecting data in my MS Access database. It gives me this error. My MS Access column is on short text because some ID are a mix of string and numbers. I just don't understand that this value  = 1007948 is error where I have the value 1007949 which is working correctly.

> ADO.NET:Execute Reader "SELECT * FROM ReqValidation WHERE ReqNo = 1007948"
>       The command text "SELECT * FROM ReqValidation WHERE ReqNo = 1007948" was executed on connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=reqRawData.accdb;
>       Persist Security Info=False;", building an OleDbDataReader using one of the CommandBehavior values.
>       Time: 8/1/2017 3:54:46 PM
>       Thread:[15912]

My code is like this:

```
public int dbCommandSelectData2(string reqID)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringData))
    {
        //using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCommandText, conn))
        //{
        //    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //    adapter.Fill(ds);
        //    return ds;
        //}

        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ReqValidation WHERE ReqNo = " + reqID + "";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //Check records are exixts or not
        if (rdr.HasRows == true)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some issues. It's funny that you're selecting on an ID which is clearly a number, but you use it as a string in your software. Also please read the [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). What is the type of the ID column?

Comment: If the ReqNo column in the database is a string rather than a numeric column then try enclosing the reqID in single quotes .

Comment: cause the data i can get is either string or number like for instance its 1007948 but the next item would something like T_R_1007948

Comment: use the query like this "SELECT * FROM ReqValidation WHERE ReqNo = '1007948'"

Comment: thanks it's working now! i forgot C# already it's a bit delicate

Comment: It's not a C# issue, it is an SQL issue.